# ASCII Art For Loop Scaling

Tags: java

For a project I am trying to scale up ASCII Art of the Space needle made with for loops.

My current code is

```
public class ASCII_ForLoops {

    public static final int scale = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        a();

        d();

        b();

        e();

        a();

        c();

        d();

        b();

    }

    public static void a() {
        for (int a = 1; a < 5 * scale; a++) {
            System.out.println("         ||");

        }
    }

    public static void b() {
        System.out.print("|");
        for (int b = 1; b < 25 * scale; b++) {

            System.out.print("\"");

        }
        System.out.print("|");

    }

    public static void c() {
        for (int c = 1; c < 17 * scale; c++) {
            System.out.println("         |%%||%%|");

        }
    }

    public static void d() {

        System.out.println("          _/||\\_");
        System.out.print("       _/");

        for (int x = 1; x < 4 * scale; x++) {
            System.out.print(":");
        }

        System.out.print("||");

        for (int x = 1; x < 4 * scale; x++)

        {
            System.out.print(":");
        }

        System.out.println("\\_");

        System.out.print("    _/");

        for (int x = 1; x < 7 * scale; x++) {
            System.out.print(":");
        }

        System.out.print("||");

        for (int x = 1; x < 7 * scale; x++)

        {
            System.out.print(":");
        }

        System.out.println("\\_");

        System.out.print(" _/");

        for (int x = 1; x < 10 * scale; x++) {
            System.out.print(":");
        }

        System.out.print("||");

        for (int x = 1; x < 10 * scale; x++)

        {
            System.out.print(":");
        }

        System.out.print("\\_");
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static void e() {
        System.out.println("   ");
        System.out.print("\\_");
        for (int x = 1; x < 12 * scale; x++) {
            System.out.print("/\\");
        }
        System.out.println("_/");

        System.out.print("  \\_");
        for (int x = 1; x < 10 * scale; x++) {
            System.out.print("/\\");
        }
        System.out.println("_/");

        System.out.print("    \\_");
        for (int x = 1; x < 8 * scale; x++) {
            System.out.print("/\\");
        }
        System.out.println("_/");

        System.out.print("      \\_");
        for (int x = 1; x < 6 * scale; x++) {
            System.out.print("/\\");
        }
        System.out.println("_/");

    }
}
```

This doesnt work though and only makes it taller instead of scaled larger along with not working on some places. If anyone could help me out with how to do it using For loops and such that would be great.

Comment: Have you considered trying to scale a simpler graphic, like a square made up of `+`, `-`, and `|`, first, to get a feel for how to solve this assignment?